# reading PHY MII registers using ethtool ioctls

Tags: linux-device-driver, ioctl

I am familiar with the mii-tool IOCTL calls which could be used to access a PHY device's MII registers something like this:

```
static int mdio_read(int skfd, int location){
 struct mii_data *mii = (struct mii_data *)&ifr.ifr_data;
  mii->reg_num = location;
  if (ioctl(skfd, SIOCGMIIREG, &ifr) < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "SIOCGMIIREG on %s failed: %s\n", ifr.ifr_name,
              strerror(errno));
      return -1;
  }
  return mii->out_value;
}
```

But the linux kenel I am using is 2.6.32 which seems not to support mii-tool IOCTLs and rather supports the newer ethtool, but I don't seem to find any ethtool subcommand which can server the same purpose as above.

How can i use ETHTOOL IOCTLs to do the same thing as I used with mii-tool ioctls, that is read phy's MII registers? Or I can't do it at all?